# Android kill all other threads when the thread UI finishes

Tags: android, multithreading

I am working on an android application that requires much work in the backroungd, so every activity in my application launches several threads.

I want to kill all those threads when the application finishes even if they still have work to do. I want to do something like this:

```
@Override    
public void onDestroy () { 
  super.onDestroy ()    
  killlAllThreads ();  
}
```